# styling not working on mobile when live

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm just trying to make a simple landing page. When I view it locally everything looks fine, but after I put it online when I look at it on mobile the background is repeating and none of the media query styles have been applied.

this is my CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

html {
  background-image: url("BKGND.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  color: #6A6D75;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  margin: 3% auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #73C23F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 0.3rem;
  margin: 5% auto 0;
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  width: 15%;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  button {
    width: 30%;
  }

  #logo {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  button {
    width: 50%;
  }

  #logo {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

and this is the site: [passporte.net](http://passporte.net)

Comment: Clearly, when you inspect element  the html tag, the code above is not the same. Hmmm, probably try clearing your cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `<head>` tag add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and in your media queries, make them like that

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 900px)
```

Comment: thanks, this fixed the media query problem. The repeating background turned out to be a 'classic me' moment where I fixed the problem and then re-uploaded the wrong file (this is why i make the big bucks lol)